# How to test validation on a model attribute is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have validation on a model attribute that only allows alphanumeric characters (letters and numbers only).

How can I test just this column without worrying about other validations?

```
validates :url, uniqueness: true,  format: { with: /[^0-9a-z]/i, 
    message: "Alphanumeric characters only." }
```

Is there a way to isolate the test just for this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

When testing for `format`, you could use [`allow_values`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb) from the [Shoulda Matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers); I think you'll have to provide some representative test cases to ensure certain values are allowed, and others are not:

```
describe 'validations' do
  describe 'for url' do
    let(:valid_urls) do
      ['Valid', 'URL', '3x4mp1e5']
    end

    let(:invalid_urls) do
      ['!nvalid', '|_|rl', 'example$']
    end

    it 'allows valid URLs' do
      expect(your_object).to allow_values(*valid_urls).for(:url)
    end

    it 'does not allow invalid URLs' do
      expect(your_object).not_to allow_values(*invalid_urls).for(:url)
        .with_message("Alphanumeric characters only.")
    end
  end
end
```

For uniqueness, you could use [`validates_uniqueness_of`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb) from the [Shoulda Matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that shoulda-matchers isn't essential here, it just makes the specs a little more concise.

Comment: @AndyWaite, yes that is true, hence the deliberate "you _could_ use..." wording.